# MemoryError frames.write(buffer) speech to text

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am trying to use the code given in below link:
https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/1.2.3/

Below is the code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.WavFile("audio.wav") as source:              # use "test.wav" as the audio source
    audio = r.record(source)                        # extract audio data from the file

try:
    print("Transcription: " + r.recognize(audio))   # recognize speech using Google Speech Recognition
except LookupError:                                 # speech is unintelligible
    print("Could not understand audio")
```

But it ran into below error:

```
>python s2t.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "s2t.py", line 4, in <module>
    audio = r.record(source)                        # extract audio data from the file
  File "C:\Users\<myuser>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 504, in record
    frames.write(buffer)
MemoryError
```

Can you please suggest how to resolve this memory or code error?

Few other details:

1. I am on windows 10
2. I tried replacing recognize(audio) with recognize_google(audio) . Same error.
3. The size of audio.wav is 750MB.

Comment: Whats your RAM ?

Comment: 16gb is my ram ..

Comment: Can anyone please suggest what i should be looking further to resolve it?

Comment: Try loading smaller audio files, if it works, then your memory is not capable of handling that much big audio representation. On disk it is 750Mb that is the compressed wav file. however when loaded into memory it might be even more bigger, and speech_recognizer library may use an internal representation like vectors or something to represent audio mathematically. Try smaller files like 10Mb etc first.